# open apps after click on notification, but I need to open my MainActivity instead of RegisterActivity

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent

I am new in android programming, I want to open my MainActivity after click on Notification, But I am not getting how to do that, and I defined action.Main and category.LAUNCHER in RegisterActivity which I open first on launch of apps, but I want to open MainActivity when I click on Notification, Please help me out and Thanks

```
<activity
            android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".UnregisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
```

Comment: I am trying to do something like that, but no effect

if (!RegisterActivity.isActive()) {

      Intent launch = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

      launch.setClass(context, RegisterActivity.class);
      launch.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      context.startActivity(launch);
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code snippet.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestID,
            intent, 0); 
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    context);
            notification = builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(appname).setWhen(when)
                    .setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(appname)
                    .setContentText(message).build();

            notificationManager.notify((int) when, notification);
```

I think it will help.

Comment: Hey, Thanks, this code is working I am now able to open apps through click on notification, but problem is that, I am getting single notification twice, any help in that matter!!!

Comment: check whether you calling this method twice or not?? or may are you receiving this msg from server side. If this answer is help you than please accept this as answer.

Comment: I have another problem the above code is working for me, but when I click on notification it is opening desire activity but I am not able to see that notification on that screen on particular textfield which I set to receive notification. Any help in that matter!!!

Comment: You have to pass your message with this activity intent and retrieve msg in your activity.

Answer (score 0):

In the activity where you are creating the notification you must declare a pending intent which will be the class triggered on click using:

`Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiverActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);`

In case of GCM notification

you can use something like this

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GcmIntentService.class.getName());
    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
```

}

where GcmIntentService.class can be your activity to be called on notification click

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

public GcmIntentService() {
    super("GcmIntentService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
    // in your BroadcastReceiver.
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
        /*
         * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM
         * will be extended in the future with new message types, just ignore
         * any message types you're not interested in, or that you don't
         * recognize.
         */
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
                    extras.toString());
        // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
            // This loop represents the service doing some work.
            for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i+1)
                        + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            // Post notification of received message.
            sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString());
            Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
        }
    }
    // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}
}
```

Comment: I am not creating any notification inside app, I am using GCM to send notification to my device, I am confuse how to do that, I google it, but couldn't get proper solution.

Comment: I am getting error that, can't override final method onHandleIntent(), what to do now??

Comment: If you find this answer helpful please vote and accept

Comment: remove override annotation